# Behaviour of String.split in java 1.6?

Tags: java, split, java-6

My code is:

```
String s = "1;;;; 23;;";
System.out.println(s.split(";").length);
```

and gives as output `5`.
The source code of `split` is:

```
public String[] split(String regex) {
        return split(regex, 0);
    }
```

and the documentation says:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument
>   split(java.lang.String,int) method with the given expression and a
>   limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not
>   included in the resulting array.
>
> The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results
>   with these expressions:
>
> ```
> Regex Result
> : { "boo", "and", "foo" }
> o { "b", "", ":and:f" }
> ```

If I print the strings I have:

```
1



 23
```

Shouldn't I get from this `1;;;; 23;;` something like `{"1", "", "", "", " 23", ""}` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, five is correct, as your quoted docs state:

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting
>   array.

Which is why the empty strings at the end of the array are omitted. If you want the empty strings, do as Evgeniy Dorofeev's answer says and specify a limit of -1.

Comment: Ok, when I read it I was  thinking of trailing empty strings in the input, not in the output array. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since limit = 0 trailing empty strings are not included. Try

```
System.out.println(s.split(";", -1).length);
```

and you will get 7

Answer (score 0):

It will split the string when ever ';' present and put into array.