# Java empty String split ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string, split

I have come across an unexpected feature in the split function of String in Java, here is my code:

```
final String line = "####";
final String[] lineData = line.split("#");
System.out.println("data: " + lineData[0] + " -- " + lineData[1]);
```

This code gives me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, whereas I would expect it to print "" and "" (two empty Strings), or maybe null and null (two null Strings).

If I change my code for

```
final String line = " # # # #";
final String[] lineData = line.split("#");
System.out.println("data: " + lineData[0] + " -- " + lineData[1]);
```

Then it prints " " and " " (the expected behaviour).

How can I make my first code not throwing an exception, and giving me an array of empty Strings?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) especially the result for o in the example.

Comment: I would recommend just debugging `split` behavior in such a way: `System.out.println (Arrays.asList(line.split("#")));`

Comment: @Raghuram, thanks, I saw this example. But don't you think this is a dangerous implementation of split? In PHP, with the explode function you get as many empty strings as you would expect (no trolling here, I like both PHP and Java). I say dangerous because if you are parsing a CSV file header with empty column, you simply miss it.

Comment: @Vaat666, this might be the answer to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056813/behaviour-of-string-split-in-java-1-6

Comment: @user3465623 Thanks! I missed this very useful post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [limit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) attribute of split method to achieve this. Try

```
final String line = "####";
final String[] lineData = line.split("#", -1);
System.out.println("Array length : " + lineData.length);
System.out.println("data: " + lineData[0] + " -- " + lineData[1]);
```

Comment: That's wierd. why would a limit of -1 work?

Comment: Thats how Java implemented the split method. ;) . Refer to the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29.  `"If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length."`

Answer (score 1):

As always, answer is written in the Javadoc

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array**.

Since your array is composed only by empty strings, they are not added to it, thus trying to access the values result in an `ArrayOutOfBoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this would do it -

```
final String line = " # ";
final String[] lineData = line.split("#");
System.out.println("data: " + lineData[0] + " -- " + lineData[1]);
```

The problem is that the empty string isn't a character.